# Making a POST request with php input type parameters?

Tags: php, json

In this code im getting JSON data from another server and im using PHP form to enter in that server,based on the  names of my input types i created some objects witch are used as parameters ,so that i can get the data from the URL and save tham into my data base.The problem is that

```
   $token = stripslashes($_REQUEST["token"]);
```

it's not working.I know my question is not clear but i just didnt know how to ask it i made my reasearch but i didnt  find what i wanted i hope u can help me.If you got any question please do ask and i will try my best to explain.

```
 <html>
   <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

 </head>
  <body >
  <?php

    require('db.php');
  $token = stripslashes($_REQUEST["token"]);
   $customerCode = stripslashes($_REQUEST["customerCode"]);
      $userName = stripslashes($_REQUEST["userName"]);
   $customerID = stripslashes($_REQUEST["customerID"]);
     $amount = stripslashes($_REQUEST["amount"]);}

     $url = 'xxxx.js';
     $data =json_encode(array('token' => $token,
             'customerCode' => $customerCode,
            'userName' =>$userName,
            'customerID' =>$customerID,
               'amount' =>$amount)
   );


   $options = array(
   'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => $data
  )  
   );
    $context= stream_context_create($options);
   $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
  if ($result === TRUE) {
    $obj= json_decode($result,true);
     mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO deposit 
(result, message, dictCount,guID,amount,customerCode,userName,dealerCode)


          mysqli_close($conn);
   }
    else{
      $obj= json_decode($result,true);
     mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO deposit (result, message) VALUES



    mysqli_close($conn);

    }


    $obj= json_decode($result,true);
      var_dump($obj);




    ?>
    <form action = "xxxxxx.js" method = "post" name = "login" >
    <input type = "text" name="token" placeholder="token" required />
 <input type = "varchar" name="customerCode"placeholder="costumerCode" />
       <input type = "varchar" name="userName" placeholder="userName"  />
     <input type = "int" name="customerID" placeholder="customerID"  />
      <input type = "int" name="amount" placeholder="amount" required />
    <input name="submit" type = "submit" value="Log In"/>
    </form>

    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: It's probably not working because in your first `mysqli_query` call you don't have a closing `"` and you don't have any values to insert. Same for the second `mysqli_query` call.

Comment: I just didnt write full code the problem is that :based on my input types i want to be the same at $data =json_encode(array('token' => $token,

Comment: One part of code gets JSON data from another server and saves tham into my data base and than is the input type form that just goes to the server.Now i want that when i put all my inputs on my php form to be the same as the parameters in  $data =json_encode(array('token' => $token)

Comment: And it's just `$token` that's not matching up? Can you dump an example of tokens not matching?

Comment: I used $token = stripslashes($_REQUEST["token"]);

Comment: An example of the data and why it's not matching is what I meant

Comment: it just doesnt recognize $token before i used real variables and the code worked just fine but i need it to match up with my input types

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Are you sending a $_REQUEST['token'] ? confirm by using `print_r($_REQUEST);`

Comment: Evrything works just fine exept the $data =json_encode(array('token' => $token,
             'customerCode' => $customerCode,
            'userName' =>$userName,
            'customerID' =>$customerID,
               'amount' =>$amount)

Comment: To tell you the truth i thought $token = stripslashes($_REQUEST["token"]) would do what i wanted and i must be wrong can u help me this ?

Comment: You need to dump the result of $_REQUEST and look what the server is actually receiving. This question is very difficult to find a solution for as we are just jumping between two comments.

Comment: Thank you man i fixed with your help